# set a password to the port requests

Tags: python, security, server

I'm writing a high-security server and opening the port from the router to connection to different computers. Let's say we opened a port from the router (192.168.x.x). Our computer is becoming a server open to the world. Each request comes from the x port. This means that the server and host are vulnerable. How to set a password on the port? (The request will not be accepted in any way other than the client software customer.)

If you have any other suggestions you can tell.

Language: python

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can’t password protect a TCP/UDP port.

However, if your software architecture is something like `server.py` - `client.py`
you can make `server.py` (which listens on port x) to expect some kind of authentication signature (like `b'AUTH CLIENTPWD ENDAUTH'`) from each `client.py` or vice versa.

Comment: Is it possible with another port if it is not with TCP AND UDP port?

Comment: @DenizAkyayla I don't think so. You can install fail2ban and password protect ssh but it has little to do with the subject.